# Create windowed exe using py2exe that accepts program arguments

Tags: python, exe, py2exe

py2exe provides a [list of options](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions) that can be used to customize how the resulting exe is set up. In particular, it provides the options `windows` and `console`, which specify whether the exe should use a console or graphical interface.

I would like my program to hide the console when executed but also accept program arguments.

When I create an exe with the `windows` option and run the program with valid arguments, the program does not seem to execute.

Here's an example. Let's say my python file is `HelloWorld.py`:

```
import sys
import getopt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'h', ['hello'])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        sys.exit(2)

    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt in ('-h', '--hello'):
            print 'Hello world!'
```

Using the setup `setup(console=['HelloWorld.py'])` and running the resulting exe with `HelloWorld.exe -h` outputs `Hello world!`.

Using the setup `setup(windows=['HelloWorld.py'])` and running the resulting exe with `HelloWorld.exe -h` outputs nothing.

Comment: `windows` just prevents the console from appearing; you can have a GUI either way. What do you want to happen with this combined exe?

Comment: I explained it poorly. When I attempt to send program arguments to a "windows" exe, the program doesn't execute.So, I don't want cmd to open when the exe is pressed, but I also would like the ability to use program args.

Comment: I don't understand why that would be; can you show some examples of what you're trying an an explanation of exactly what happens?

Comment: Are you able to provide a minimal *complete* example? Try to write a toy application that simply checks for the command line arguments and show exactly how you are building the `exe`s, so that we can test the behaviour you see.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an explanation on how py2exe manages stdout and sterr
when it packages applications as console application or windows applications at the following link:

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/StderrLog

Answer (score -1):

windows option is for GUI application (wxpython etc) which can catch the stdout and show it in the GUI but without implementing such thing you will need cmd window to print stdout by "print" statement. For example, in wxpython you can start the app with redirect=True option to capture the stdout.

http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.App-class.html

```
import wx

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(True)
```

> redirect - Should sys.stdout and sys.stderr be redirected? Defaults to
>   True on Windows and Mac, False otherwise. If filename is None then
>   output will be redirected to a window that pops up as needed.

Comment: I'm using Tkinter, not wxpython. And I am using cmd but not seeing print statements appear when using the `windows` option with py2exe.